# Div flicker when fading in and out with timeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility, display

one div I am using like a done msg. It should appear when a process is finished and disappear after a few seconds. For that I coded this little code snippet:

```js
function showProcessFinishedMsg(msg) {
    var done_msg = document.getElementById("done_msg");
    var done_msg_text = document.getElementById("done_msg_text");

    done_msg_text.innerHTML = msg;
    unfade(done_msg);
    setTimeout(fade(done_msg),60000);
  }

  //fading in
  function unfade(element) {
      var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
      element.style.display = 'block';
      var timer = setInterval(function () {
          if (op >= 1){
              clearInterval(timer);
          }
          element.style.opacity = op;
          element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
          op += op * 0.1;
      }, 10);
  }

  //fading out
  function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

```css
.done_msg {
 height: 50px;
 width: 80%;
 left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.done_msg_text {
 padding-left: 30px;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="done_msg" id="done_msg" style="display: none;">
  <img src="./done.png" width="33px" height="auto">
  <p class="done_msg_text" id="done_msg_text">icbsiudbisbdvoaodvnoda</p>
</div>

<button onclick="showProcessFinishedMsg('Maybe it works, in a different universe.')">Testbutton</button>
```

But as you can see I have the problem, that it works not smooth. And it flickers so weirdly. Hope anyone can help me.
~filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with:

```
setTimeout(fade(done_msg), 60000);
```

Here, you are calling the `fade` function when this line is executed, not every minute like you think you are.

The first parameter of `setTimeout` is supposed to be a function which can be executed, however, you are executing the function right away, and so you're setting the first argument to be the return value of `fade` which is `undefined`.

This causes your `unfade` and `fade` functions to run simultaneously, thus causing the flicker. Instead, wrap `fade(done_msg)` in its own function:

```
setTimeout(_ => fade(done_msg), 60000);
```

See working example below:

```js
function showProcessFinishedMsg(msg) {
  var done_msg = document.getElementById("done_msg");
  var done_msg_text = document.getElementById("done_msg_text");

  done_msg_text.innerHTML = msg;
  unfade(done_msg);
  setTimeout(_ => fade(done_msg), 2000);
}

//fading in
function unfade(element) {
  var op = 0.1; // initial opacity
  element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
  element.style.display = 'flex';
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 10);
}

//fading out
function fade(element) {
  var op = 1; // initial opacity
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
.done_msg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.done_msg_text {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="done_msg" id="done_msg" style="display: none;">
  <img src="./done.png" width="33px" height="auto">
  <p class="done_msg_text" id="done_msg_text">icbsiudbisbdvoaodvnoda</p>
</div>

<button onclick="showProcessFinishedMsg('Maybe it works, in a different universe.')">Testbutton</button>
```

Comment: Oh thanks. But one more thing. When the div gets visible the content is not centered anymore. When you remove this "style="display: none;"" from the HTML div, you see how it should look like. Why this happens?

Comment: @FilipDegenhart because you are doing `element.style.display = 'block';` in your JS. Change that to `element.style.display = 'flex';`. I've updated the snippet